# Decompress images to use on a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, image-processing, compression

I currently working on a project that i need to display large images on a UITableView,this is very common problem for a lot of developers and learning with they threads i reached to the following procedure:

NOTE:The large images i refer,they all have 300x300px(600x600px,retina) and about 200kb,JPEG

1. Create a NSOperationQueue;
2. Download images asynchronously(Each image has 600x600px,corresponding to the @2x image);
3. Resize and create the non retina image(300x300px image);
4. Decompress both images;
5. Store all images on a NSCache;

After all that procedures have finished i update my UITableView on the main thread.I'am using a UITableViewCell subclass to draw all my needed content(As seen on Apple's sample codes).The main problem is that i'm confused about step 4(decompress images),my doubts:

NOTE:I'm currently storing my decompressed images on a NSCache.

- Should i decompress the images and store then as UIImage's or NSData's?
- How can i store the decompressed images?(NSCache,NSMutableArray...)
- What is the best way to pass the decompressed image to my UITableViewCell subclass?

NOTE:I'm using the decompression code presented here:[link](http://ioscodesnippet.com/post/10924101444/force-decompressing-uiimage-in-background-to-achieve)

Answer (score 2):

- You can't really store an `UIImage` object to disk, but you can turn it to `NSData` using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`
- Using UIImage will give you cache out of the box, I bet it's the most efficient you can get
- Just put the image into UIImageView, Apple spent a lot of time on making image rendering fast.

That said, your images are not particularly big, especially for retina devices, I would advice looking at something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library that has a complete and tested solution for this problem.

Plus, you can look up the code of [AFImageRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFImageRequestOperation.m) which does exactly what you need: download, store, cache, reuse.

Comment: Ok,i got your point,but i already tried to use a UIImageView and things just got slower.As you said 'Apple spent a lot of time on making image rendering fast',yes thats true but i really need to work on images decompression because as my context require i need to draw images on 'drawrect'

Comment: Sure, then look at the code I linked for image download operation, the key is that everything runs on background, while only updating main thread with complete UIImage